# Azure App Service Console: Commands will not execute, crashes console

Tags: azure, api, console, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Any command I execute from within my app service's web-based Azure console fails:

[image]

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot>dir
function(e){if(void 0===e&&(e="legacy"),this._body instanceof b)return this._body.toString();if(this._body instanceof ArrayBuffer)switch(e){case"legacy":return String.fromCharCode.apply(null,new Uint16Array(this._body));case"iso-8859":return String.fromCharCode.apply(null,new Uint8Array(this._body));default:throw new Error("Invalid value for encodingHint: "+e)}return null==this._body?"":"object"==typeof this._body?JSON.stringify(this._body,null,2):this._body.toString()}con
```

It then completely hangs until I close out of the web-based console and refresh the portal.azure page. I've been searching for a solution but this issue doesn't seem to have been reported.

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with the scm website.

Comment: Please hit the restart in azure portal，both the main and SCM sites get restarted. If it helps you, pls let me know.

Comment: Is there any progress?

Answer (score 1):

The console blade utilizes a connection to Kudu. If you are in an ILB ASE you'll need direct network connectivity to Kudu for the page to load. If your client machine does not have access to Kudu you'll see the error above.

Comment: This can be caused by a misconfiguration in the networking "Access Restrictions".

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new API app (the resource I was trying to deploy to) and switching to it.

One comment suggested reconnecting the storage, but my resource didn't have one.

Call it blue-green deployment if you want to feel better about using this hack.

See [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/132511/azure-console-fails-any-command-and-shows-code-containing-invalid-value-for-enc/132970#132970) on Webmasters StackExchange