# Azure Web App Service Console non-functional

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Upon entering any command (e.g. dir), our Azure web app console brings up a small throbber and shows a "Failed to execute the command" error message.  It's been quite awhile since I tried these commands but they definitely used to work and now don't.

How do I go about looking for more details to figure out what's wrong?

The last answer of [Azure App Service Console: Commands will not execute, crashes console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65315173/azure-app-service-console-commands-will-not-execute-crashes-console) suggests that it might be related to ILB ASE or Kudu connections but I'm not sure how to assess whether that's relevant to our situation

Answer (score 0):

Reached out Microsoft and they made me aware that this is a networking security issue that can be solved by adding access rules under Networking.

You can verify the situation is applicable by clicking the Go link under Advanced Tools which would take you to the Kudu console.  If you get a 403, you need to create an allow rule and you're good to go.